# 502 Error - Consistent, but not consistent

Tags: azure, iis

I have a web server set up through Azure, and when I follow a specific web flow it crashes the server with a 502 Bad Gateway error.  I can follow most any web flow without getting this error, but if I follow a very specific flow it generates the error.

What is odd, is this is only replicated by one person.  This person is able to cause the error on multiple computers within the network, and when looking at it on their mobile phone which is off the buildings network (on cellular network).

On our site, we have tried to replicate the error and have failed.  We have used multiple browsers, multiple networks, multiple cell phones on multiple networks, and are unable to repeat the 502 Error.

Any suggestions on where we could look to start debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You haven't given any details at all about the app. Not sure what anyone will be able to do, aside from guess. I'd suggest editing your question to provide more detail. We don't even know how you deployed it in Azure (web app? VM? Cloud Service?)

Comment: It is on an Azure VM, Microsoft Server running IIS.  It is a C# web app.